# How to configure apache ssl with reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a flask app running on port 8080 and I want to use Apache as a reverse proxy as well as redirect http to https.

"/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog /home/helloworld/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/helloworld/logs/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/helloworld/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/helloworld/certs/key.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have a working nginx config to do the same this but I want to use apache in production.
Here is the nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /home/helloworld/certificate/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/helloworld/certificate/key.pem;

    access_log /var/log/ex_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/ex_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you test (your config seems fine)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `Redirect` which only matches / , this should be better (but there are other ways to do the same) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```